# About the double orthogonality of the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, hilbert-space

Consider the usual Hamiltonian describing the motion of a particle,

$$\hat H = \frac {\hat P^2}{2m} + V(r),$$

where for simplicity the problem can be considered in 1D on the semiaxis $[a, \infty)$ , and $V(r)$ real and positive. We know that the solutions, $\psi (r; k)$ are orthogonal in the sense that

$$ \ \int _0^{\infty} dr \ \psi^*(r; k) \ \psi (r; k') = \delta (k, k') .\tag{1}$$

where $\delta (k, k')$ can be Kronecker, or Dirac, depending on whether $k$ is discrete or continuous.

**My question**: is there any proof that the **other orthogonality** holds? I.e. a proof for

$$ \ \int _{- \infty} ^{\infty} dk\ \psi^*(r; k) \ \psi (r'; k) = \delta (r, r') .\tag{2}$$

Here we have $\delta$ Dirac, and the integral is over $k > 0$.
I repeat, I am asking about a rigorous proof, and for **this** Hamiltonian, not for simpler ones. Note that the solutions $\psi(r; k)$ don't necessarily have a bounded norm, see equation (1).

Comment: You are asking for a "rigorous proof", while you haven't even specified what type of a potential you are working with (where is it defined? How does it act?), *nor* have you given the Hilbert space that you would like to consider. This already excludes the possibility of a rigorous answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @Danu : One can assume that the potential has the form of the nuclear potential, i.e. a potential well limited by a potential barrier of finite height and that vanishes for  $r \ -> \infty $

Comment: @Sofia in that case the question should say so. (By the way, use `\to` in MathJax, i.e. `r\to\infty`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "resolution of the identity", in case you wanted more information. The identity depends on the eigenvectors of $H$ forming a *complete* orthonormal basis. Thus,
$$\langle k | k'\rangle = \delta_{k,k'}$$
Now consider the matrix
$$O = \sum_q |q\rangle \langle q |,$$
where the ket $\left|q\right\rangle$ represents the wavefunction in the following sense: $\langle r | q \rangle = \psi(r;q)$ in your notation. In the position representation, $O(r,r') = \langle r | O | r'\rangle = \int\!dq\,\psi^*(r;q) \,\psi(r';q)$

We can find out what it's elements are in the $k$ basis as follows:
$$\langle k | O | k'\rangle = \sum_q \langle k | q\rangle \langle q | k'\rangle = \delta_{k,k'}.$$
Thus the matrix $O$ is just the identity matrix. In the position representation 
$$ O(r,r') = \int _{- \infty} ^{\infty} dq\ \psi_q(r) \, \psi_q^* (r') = \delta (r - r'),$$
where of course $\delta(r-r')$ is the identity matrix.

**Edit**: As requested, form the operator
$$ O(r,r') = \int _{- \infty} ^{\infty} dq\ \psi_q(r) \, \psi_q^* (r').$$
Now, let us evaluate it in your basis. In other words, we ask what are the matrix elements $O_{k,k'} = O(k,k')$:
$$O(k,k') = \int\!dr\,dr' \psi^*_k(r) O(r,r') \psi_{k'}(r').$$
This becomes 
$$\begin{eqnarray}O(k,k') &=& \int\!dr\,dr' \int\!dq\, \psi^*_k(r) \psi_q(r) \, \psi_q^* (r')\psi_{k'}(r') \\ &=& \int\!dq\, \delta(k-q)\, \delta(k-q')\\
&=& \delta(k-k')\end{eqnarray}.$$
If something is the identity in one basis, it is the identity in every basis, but we should demonstrate this. Any good wave function admits an expansion in your basis, so
$$\alpha(r) = \int\!dq\, \alpha(q) \,\psi_q(r)$$
From this, and orthonormality, we get
$$\begin{eqnarray}\int\!dr\, \psi^*_q(r) \alpha(r) \, &=& \int\!dr\, \psi^*_q(r) \int\!dk\, \alpha(k) \,\psi_k(r)\\
&=&  \int\!dk\, \alpha(k) \int\!dr\, \psi^*_q(r) \,\psi_k(r)\\
&=&  \int\!dk\, \alpha(k) \delta(k-q)\\
&=&  \alpha(q)\end{eqnarray}$$
Or in other words,
$$\alpha(q) = \int\!dr\, \alpha(r) \,\psi^*_q(r)$$
Now we demonstrate the sifting property, which is enough to show that we have a delta function:
$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
\int\!dr'\, O(r,r') \alpha(r')  &=& \int\!dr'\,dq\, \psi_q(r) \, \psi_q^* (r') \,\alpha(r') \\
&=& \int\!dq\, \psi_q(r) \,\alpha(q)\\
 &=& \alpha(r)
\end{eqnarray}.$$
This must be true for any $\alpha(r)$ under consideration, hence $O(r,r') = \delta(r-r')$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19655/discussion-on-answer-by-lionelbrits-about-the-double-orthogonality-of-the-eigenf).

Answer (score 5):

I will give you some rigor, since it seems what you are looking for.

The rigor takes the form of the very famous spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators.

***First of all, a simple example to elucidate***: a purely discrete spectrum, that forms an orthonormal eigenbasis of the hilbert space (i.e. the operator $H$ is either compact or with compact resolvent). I would like to remark that usually in quantum mechanics $H$ is not compact, and only rarely with compact resolvent (one example of the latter is the harmonic oscillator). In that case, we have a countable set of eigenfunctions $\{\psi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, that satisfy:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_{\psi_n}=\mathrm{id}\; ,\tag{1}$$
where $P_{\psi_n}$ is the orthogonal projector on $\psi_n$ and $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity operator. What you write as $\overline{\psi}_n(y)\psi_n(x)$ is sometimes called the "integral kernel" of the projection operator, i.e. the "function" $K(x,y)$ such that
$$(P_{\psi_n}\phi)(x)=\int K(x,y)\phi(y)dy\; ,$$
where the integral is intended over the whole span of the variable $y$ of the Hilbert space (in your example from $0$ to $\infty$). The integral kernel of the identity operator is the Dirac's delta $\delta(x-y)$. So Equation (1) above written for integral kernels yields
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{\psi}_n(y)\psi_n(x) = \delta(x-y)$$
as you wish.

***Now to the general case***: In the case where $H$ is self-adjoint but has continuous spectrum, there is no eigenbasis. Nevertheless, you can still give meaning to the spectral theorem, introducing the so called spectral family, that is a projection-valued measure. Without entering into details, you can think of it as a family of projections that can be integrated. Call this family $(P_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ (since the spectrum is continuous, now $\lambda$ ranges over the reals). Equation (1) takes in this case the form
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}dP_\lambda=\mathrm{id}\; .\tag{2}$$
So also for equation (2) we see that the integral kernel of the spectral family, integrated over all the spectrum, is the $\delta(x-y)$. Now ***with an abuse of notation*** you can think at this spectral family as the projection on the ["generalized eigenfunctions"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space), integrated over the spectrum. If you call this family $\{f_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$, then the integral kernel of $dP_\lambda$ (but I stress that this is, mathematically speaking, a very unclear statement) $\bar{f}_\lambda(y)f_\lambda(x)d\lambda$ then you obtain your sought equality from (2) in its integral kernel version:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\bar{f}_\lambda(y)f_\lambda(x) d\lambda =\delta(x-y)\; .$$

***The morale***: on strictly mathematical terms, it is a trivial application of the spectral theorem to show that the integral kernel of a spectral family integrated over the spectrum is the dirac's delta. The interpretation of this as "orthogonality" of the generalized eigenfunctions is physically acceptable for sure, but mathematically at least borderline.

***Edit***: For those interested in the expansion of Hilbert space vectors w.r.t. generalized eigenfunctions, and some rigorous discussion of the spectral theorem in a version suitable to utilize generalized eigenfunctions I suggest a look at this [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01159969). Obviously this is a mathematical paper, therefore a solid math background is needed.

Comment: what is a resolvent? I am not sure about the meaning of this concept. Can you explain simply? And with thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easier to see if you write them as Dirac braket form.

Equation (1) is

$$\langle k\lvert k'\rangle = \delta(k,k') = \int \mathrm{d}r\, \langle k\lvert r\rangle\langle r\lvert k'\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}r\, \psi^*(r;k) \psi (r;k')$$

Equation (2) is

$$\langle r\lvert r'\rangle = \delta(r,r') = \int \mathrm{d}k\,\langle r\lvert k\rangle\langle k\lvert r'\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}k\,\psi(r;k)\psi^*(r';k) $$

Comment: @Sofia if you don't understand, you can certainly say so, and you can _ask_ for specific points in the answer to be clarified, but it's rather presumptious (i.e. rude) to act as though you have the authority to tell people how to change their answers.

Comment: In any case I consider this a fairly elegant answer. (Assuming $k$ is defined and integrable over the relevant range, of course.)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, although for someone who has been doing QM for a long time, the notation becomes pretty transparent.

Comment: @Sofia perhaps _for you_, the integrals need to be written in detail. For me, this answer is quite satisfactory. Of course, there's nothing wrong for requesting that an answerer show certain details; it is your question and you're certainly entitled to give answerers feedback on how well their answers address your question. My point is only that the way that you did so in your comment above is rather rude.